Biomejs runs linter with no errors, even if there are errors shown in the file
Here is my config:
{
    "$schema": "https://biomejs.dev/schemas/1.6.4/schema.json",
    "organizeImports": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "linter": {
        "enabled": true,
        "rules": {
            "recommended": true
        }
    },
    "files": {
        "ignore": ["./.next/server", "./.next/static"]
    }
}

When I run lint, it's all green, even if in my file index.js I have declared variable which is assigned to a non-existing function:
const test = myFunction(); // Cannot find name "myFunction" Did you mean "Function"?

So also the index.js file is highlighted red, but linter still runs with no errors. I tried to break different Rules mentioned in the documentation, but none of those break my linter: biome lint .

That's expected (at least, for the code you provided), because the recommended set of rules doesn't include noUndeclaredViarables.
Check the playground, and then, on the left, try to change "Recommended" to "All". You'll see the difference.
